# Organize heavy python imports

Tags: python, import, project-organization

About 25% of my code depends on the modules: Traits, tvtk, ... which are quite heavy to import. It typically takes a good 2 seconds on my machine (and more on other).

My modules are organized as the following

```
mainmodule
|--submodule1
|--submodule2
   |--subsubmodule1
   |--subsubmodule2
|--submodule3
|--submodule4
   |--subsubmodule1
   |--subsubmodule2
```

In these, the submodule1 and submodule2 use Traits. That means 75% of the time, if I call **import mainmodule**, I will have to wait for the heavy modules to be imported but then they won't be used.

How do I organize my imports so that I can lower my import time?

Maybe there is a way to do something like:

```
import mainmodule
```

and have

```
mainmodule
|--submodule3
|--submodule4
   |--subsubmodule1
   |--subsubmodule2
```

And only call:

```
import mainmodule.heavy
```

to have everything

Comment: What? It's extremely unclear what you're asking.

Comment: Answering a different question: you can try putting traits, etc. in a zip file and put that zip file on the PYTHONPATH. This may reduce overall import time because it's a lot fewer file accesses.

Comment: @Falmarri: I updated the question, hopefully the intention is clearer; @Andrew Dalke: How do I know which file is part of Traits?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like what you want is a way so that importing `mainmodule` doesn't automatically import `submodule1` and `submodule2`, which take a long time to load.

That's pretty easy, actually. You can import `submodule1` and `submodule2` only in functions that need them. Or move those functions into a separate module called `mainmodule_heavy.py`.

(Or you could [hack the Python module system to load modules lazily](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/473888-lazy-module-imports/). But that kind of hack tends to cause problems, and it sounds unnecessary for your case.)

Answer (score 3):

You can put some code like this within a function / module:-

```
def heavy():
    global x
    global y
    import x, y

def mainmodule():
    if heavy not in globals():
        import heavy
```

Actually, this wouldn't work within the same program, as a function cannot be imported. Also, you'd want to check for a **string** within globals, not the module itself. So, instead:-

```
def heavy():
    global x
    global y
    import x, y

def mainmodule():
    if 'x' not in globals() or 'y' not in globals():
        heavy()
```